# Autofac - InstancePerHttpRequest ambiguous call

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, autofac

I need to reference both `Autofac.Integration.Mvc` and `Autofac.Integration.Web` dll's in my MVC3 project and am encountering the following naming conflict with the `InstancePerHttpRequest()` method:

> This call is ambiguous between Autofac.Integration.Mvc and Autofac.Integration.Web

I need both dll's to be referenced as my project is MVC3 but elements are integrating SQL SSRS reports which demand the use of ASPX pages because of the `ReportViewer` control is required. I need to resolve my my service classes to call functionality from my APSX code behind. Any ideas how I can resolve this naming conflict please or is this totally incompatible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`InstancePerHttpRequest` is an extension method and as such it is declared as a normal static method in the classes `Autofac.Integration.Web.RegistrationExtensions` and `Autofac.Integration.Mvc.RegistrationExtensions`.

The solution is to call the method explicitly:

```
Autofac.Integration.Web.RegistrationExtensions
         .InstancePerHttpRequest(yourBuilder.Register(c => ...)
```

Or to include just one of these two namespaces (its not the reference that makes the ambiguity):

```
using Autofac.Integration.Web;
using Autofac.Integration.Mvc;
```